# Apache Beam Python WriteToBigtable Possible to Deadletter?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

As the title says,

Is it possible to write to a deadletter topic in pubsub when WriteToBigtable() fails? I know its possible with Bigquery but haven't seen anything on BigTable.

I am using the Apache Beam python library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current WriteToBigTable doesn't return failed records..However, you could write your custom PTransform to return failed mutations based on your requirements.
The in built transform uses google python client library underneath for writing to big table. You could leverage it's source code and add exception handling to output your exception types.

Source Code : https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.html#WriteToBigTable